# Why "fdisk -l" does not give any output in terminal?

Tags: fdisk

When I do `fdisk -l` in terminal there is no output? What can be the probable reason? How to fix it?

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: These thing happen when you switch from RHEL to ubuntu. So obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Because [**fdisk**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/fdisk.8.html) is a menu-driven program for creation and manipulation of partition tables. Therefore it requires `sudoers` or `root` access

try using

`sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: It is so tedious to do sudo for simple tasks. Anyway that was obvious. I used RHEL earlier and things were straight forward.

Comment: Maybe RHEL follows the footsteps only to be controlled by admins , here it avails everyone to do changes  ( Ubuntu - Linux for Human beings  + Admins too) :P

Comment: \m/ absolutely agree :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix the command with sudo, then enter your password.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `sudo fdisk -l`  or first `sudo su` then `fdisk -l`.